# Get latitude & longitude value automatically for praytimes

Tags: javascript, html

I am using [Praytimes JS](http://praytimes.org/code/v2/js/PrayTimes.jsmes&hb=HEAD&f=v2/js) to display muslim prayer times but for each location I have to manually add latitude & longitude of that location.

How can I get latitude & longitude values using [W3 GeoLocation](https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_geolocation.asp) for below codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    prayTimes.setMethod('MWL'); 
    var date = new Date(); // today
    var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, [23.022505, 72.5713621]);
    var list = ['Fajr', 'Sunrise', 'Dhuhr', 'Asr', 'Maghrib', 'Isha', 'Midnight'];

    var html = '<table id="timetable">';
    html += '<tr><th colspan="2">'+ date.toLocaleDateString()+ '</th></tr>';
    for(var i in list) {
        html += '<tr><td>'+ list[i]+ '</td>';
        html += '<td>'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+ '</td></tr>';
    }
    html += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

I want to make this process automate.

Comment: Automate which process? Currently you have hardcoded coordinates. How did you try to use the geolocation api?

Comment: This http://praytimes.org/code/v2/js/examples/simple.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadTable(position) {
        prayTimes.setMethod('MWL'); 
        var date = new Date(); // today
        var times = prayTimes.getTimes(date, [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]);
        var list = ['Fajr', 'Sunrise', 'Dhuhr', 'Asr', 'Maghrib', 'Isha', 'Midnight'];

        var html = '<table id="timetable">';
        html += '<tr><th colspan="2">'+ date.toLocaleDateString()+ '</th></tr>';
        for(var i in list)  {
            html += '<tr><td>'+ list[i]+ '</td>';
            html += '<td>'+ times[list[i].toLowerCase()]+ '</td></tr>';
        }
        html += '</table>';
        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = html;
    }

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(loadTable);
    }
</script>
```